# Sort dates and format date in Python

Tags: python, date, sorting

I'm working in a code that use date and time. I use `.sort()` for sort the elements but I have some problems with the date and time format.

```
List_with_Dict=[
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:1:43', 'Values': ' 46.2'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:51:43', 'Values': ' 45.3'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 1:21:47', 'Values': ' 23.0'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:17:41', 'Values': ' 46.5'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:59:19', 'Values': ' 46.1'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:41:43', 'Values': ' 43.9'}]
List_with_Dict.sort(reverse=False, key=lambda e: e['Date_Time']) 

for elements in List_with_Dict:
    print(elements)
```

The output is:

```
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:41:43', 'Values': ' 43.9'}
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:51:43', 'Values': ' 45.3'}
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:59:19', 'Values': ' 46.1'}
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:17:41', 'Values': ' 46.5'}
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:1:43', 'Values': ' 46.2'}
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 1:21:47', 'Values': ' 23.0'}
```

As you can see, the two last dictionaries have a different format and can not be sorted. There any solution for this, like a different format date? Or do I need to work in the dictionaries in change the time (`h:m:s to hh:mm:ss`)?

Comment: Convert the string representing `Date_Time` to a `datetime.datetime` and then it will sort properly, even if the years are different. The first four values appear sorted but that is just because they are in the same 12-hour period on the same day, in other words, in only seems to work okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `for` loop to correct the time formats:

```
List_with_Dict=[
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:1:43', 'Values': ' 46.2'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:51:43', 'Values': ' 45.3'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 1:21:47', 'Values': ' 23.0'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:17:41', 'Values': ' 46.5'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:59:19', 'Values': ' 46.1'},
{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:41:43', 'Values': ' 43.9'}]

for d in List_with_Dict:
    date, time = d["Date_Time"].split()
    time = ':'.join([i.ljust(2, '0') for i in time.split(':')])
    d["Date_Time"] = f"{date} {time}"

print(List_with_Dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:10:43', 'Values': ' 46.2'},
 {'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:51:43', 'Values': ' 45.3'},
 {'Date_Time': '06/12/20 10:21:47', 'Values': ' 23.0'},
 {'Date_Time': '06/12/20 14:17:41', 'Values': ' 46.5'},
 {'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:59:19', 'Values': ' 46.1'},
 {'Date_Time': '06/12/20 13:41:43', 'Values': ' 43.9'}]
```

Explanation:

1. First, iterate through the list of dictionaries:

```
for d in List_with_Dict:
```

2. Get the value of the `"Date_Time"` key of each dictionary of the iterations, split the values by the space, and assign the
   resulting two strings to two variables as the date strings and time strings.

```
date, time = d["Date_Time"].split()
```

3. Split the time string by the colon, pad each time element with 2 `"0"`s, and join the elements with the colon again.

```
time = ':'.join([i.ljust(2, '0') for i in time.split(':')])
```

4. Reassign the value to the `"Date_Time"` key of each dictionary, with the converted time string:

```
d["Date_Time"] = f"{date} {time}"
```